# Listing input values separately in Python

Tags: python, split

I am using Python 3.4 and I've written the Python code below. What I want is to save a user's name and age to a text file when they enter it. I want to see the input comma-separated line-by-line.

I tried `.split()` but it did not work. I would be happy for any help, thank you.

```
ages = [] 
name = ' ' 
age = ' ' 
fileName = 'demo.txt' 
#you can do it csv 
WRITE = 'w'
APPEND = 'a' 
while name != 'done':
   name = input('what is your name: ')
   age = input('what is your age: ')
   guests.append(name)
   ages.append(age)

guests.remove('done')
ages.remove('done')
file = open(fileName, mode = WRITE)
file.writelines(guests)
file.writelines(ages)
file.close()
```

Comment: Please explain why it is not working, and include error message you get.

Comment: I do not get error but output is not the way I want. Below answer solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Improve grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would write a file with guests and ages

```
with  open(fileName, mode = WRITE) as inpt:
    for i in range(len(guests)):
        inpt.write(guests[i] + ", " + ages[i] + "\n")
```

demo.txt

```
Andi, 12
Bertha, 34
Claus, 99
```

Or this way:

```
with  open(fileName, mode = WRITE) as inpt:
    inpt.write(",".join(guests))
    inpt.write("\n")
    inpt.write(",".join(ages))
```

demo.txt

```
Andi, Bertha, Claus
12, 34, 99
```

Comment: @Emrah, please don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem. ;)